# Navigation Bar too big how do i make it smaller

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

[The Red needs to be higher up the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G7io.png)

i am having trouble making a navigation bar smaller as seen in the image the navigation bar is taking up a large portion of the screen how can i make this navigation bar fixed regardless of which page you are on

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
var body: some View {
NavigationView {
ZStack {
Color(.red)

                VStack {
                    Text("Team Name - Summary")
                }
                
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Image("ic-logo")
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal){
                        Text("Team Name")
                            .font(.navTitle)
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            TeamView()
                        } label: {
                            Image("ic-people")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }

}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
HomeView()
}
}

struct TeamView: View {
var body: some View {
Text("Team View")
}
}
```

also need the navigation bar to stay in the same place and not double up when going to a new page which also has a navigation bar

Comment: You should only have one `NavigationView` in your hierarchy. You likely have more than one or are navigating to `HomeView` again, leading to multiple copies of the bar. You should keep `NavigationView` at the top of your hierarchy and not navigate to the owner of that component again.